# Where do I define Sunspot/solr configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I see in the sunspot documentation that to define the default number of results I should use:

Sunspot.config.pagination.default_per_page = 12

I have tried adding that line to application.rb but it doesn't work. Where exactly should I define this setting?

Comment: are you getting any error or is it just ignoring the setting?

Answer (score 4):

Just put it in an initializer e.g. `config/initializers/sunspot.rb` and it will work fine!

Comment: I am glad that worked for you! You could also accept my answer if it was the one you expected! Thanks!